# Unable to send mails in C# using Outgoing Mail Servers like Gmail/Yahoo using port 465

Tags: c#, email

Using the System.Net.Mail namespace the code used is as below.

```
MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage("example@gmail.com", "example@gmail.com",

"write your subject Here ", "Hi,This is the test message ");

MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;

NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new NetworkCredential("example@gmail.com","xxxxxxxx");

    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);

    mailClient.EnableSsl = true;

    mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

    mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

    mailClient.Credentials = mailAuthentication;

    mailClient.Send(MyMailMessage);
```

Using the above code timeout exception happens if 465 port is used.
25 port works fine.
In the case of yahoo account both 465 and 25 gives failure sending mail.

Is there anyway 465 port can be supported for sending mails using gmail or yahoo account.

Refered the following link
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/06/02/system-net-mail-with-ssl-to-authenticate-against-port-465.aspx

Is states that Windows Mail uses System.Net.Mail to send messages - wont work with Implicit SSL.

Is there any solution to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a try/catch block? What error is thrown?

Comment: can you show us what exception you are getting?provide detail stack trace

Comment: Not sure if helps, but I send emails with google smpt port 587. It works.

Comment: Yes it works with Gmail Smtp port 587. But yahoo supports 465 port. So we cant send emails with yahoo smtp.

Comment: Dgibbs, we are using try/catch block. The error shows that the operation has timed out.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the problem but .NET built-in mail class doesn't support the needed implicit SSL method.You have to use third-party SMTP client components for this purpose which are capable of both explicit and implicit SSL.

Comment: Thanks Cris. Hopefully .Net mail class will support Implicit SSL in further releases.